# How many ways can 10 letters be posted in 5 post boxes, if each of the post boxes can take more than 10 letters?

Tags: combinatorics

I have this question:

> How many ways can 10 letters be posted in 5 post boxes, if each of the post boxes can take more than 10 letters?

I solved using the approach that:
10 letter can be put in each letter box hence total ways = $10*10*10*10*10=10^5$

But the actual answer is 5 to the power 10, how is this possible?

Comment: There's a mistake in your question,you did not mention the capacity of each postbox.This needs editing.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer it's assumed to be infinity,if it's not mentioned in such questions.

Comment: I have edited the question but my edit is not getting approved.I could show you the error in the question more clearly if it was approved and was visible.I searched your question on google before mentioning your error.So i am sure that there is a mistake in your question.

Comment: ok let's just say it's assumed to be infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the 10 letters can be stored in any of the 5 postboxes.
So, the first letter has 5 options(postboxes),so does the second letter and so on and so forth for all of the 10 letters.
i.e. $5*5*5*….*5$ (upto 10 times) = $5 ^ {10}$.

Comment: but if i do the opposite with the letterbox, like i stated in the question, what is wrong with my method, it should also be the correct answer, kindly help me with this confusion

Comment: You need to understand that you are going to store letters in a postbox right?Not the opposite.Each letter has 5 postboxes in which they can be stored.And the question asks in **How many ways** the letters can be stored.